# Adding a new object to context

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, mvvm, crud

So apparently I don't understand EF well enough yet. Someone here at SO suggested I shouldn't keep a context object open for the life of my application, so I changed things slightly and now here is how it is currently working:

1. I read required data from the DB using EF and store it in an `ObservableCollection(Of MyEntity)`.
2. The application keeps adding new objects to this collection, modifying/deleting existing objects in the ObservableCollection.
3. Upon application exit or Save button, I try to submit changes back to the DB, but apparently cannot. Here's the submission code.

   ```
   For Each entity In MyObservableCollection
     If entity.EntityState = EntityState.Added OrElse entity.EntityState = EntityState.Detached Then
       Dim key = context.CreateEntityKey(entitySetName, entity)
       entity.EntityKey = key
       context.FilmTypes.Attach(entity)
     ElseIf entity.EntityState = System.Data.EntityState.Modified Then
       Dim originalItem As Object = Nothing
       Dim key = context.CreateEntityKey(entitySetName, entity)
       If context.TryGetObjectByKey(key, originalItem) Then
           context.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, entity)
       End If
     End If
   Next

   context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave)
   ```

EF tells me that there is already an object with the same key. My PK column is defined as Identity in the Model, so I expect it to auto-generate a temporary key (just like old good DataSets did).

How exactly do we work in "disconnected" mode in EF?

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself. The code for Modified state is correct. For new objects, it should be like this:

```
If entity.EntityState = EntityState.Added OrElse entity.EntityState = EntityState.Detached Then
    context.FilmTypes.AddObject(entity)
```

No need to specify key parameter. EF will take care of it.